# Fantasy font – different in IE & Edge, Chrome, FF

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, microsoft-edge, font-family

I have found *[Fantasy](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#fantasy-def)* font loading differently in **IE** & **Edge** vs **Chrome** vs **FF**.

```html
<p style="font-family: fantasy;font-size:200%">
The quickest brownest fox jumps over the laziest dog.
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font-family `fantasy`, like `monospace` or `sans-serif`, doesn't refer to a specific font. It just asks the browser to fill in the best it can do. Different browsers can and do choose different fonts to fill these roles (and some browsers let the user choose their own)

If you need it text to appear in exactly the same across browsers, you should specify a specific font (and include it as a webfont if you can't trust it to already be installed on all of your visitor's computers)

Comment: Very interesting answer. I did not know that at all. However, I cannot help feeling that this is another example of why we are at the tail end of the multimedia epoch. Hypermedia included. This is pointless overengineering nobody needs. And it is all going wasm and ai.

Comment: @Sentinel It is like this because of the past, not the present. Even getting more than a few fonts on a computer would have been challenging -- and a site wouldn't know what their names are! With these generic font families, you can explain to the browser what you *need* and allow it to work out the unimportant detail of the font's name and Bezier curves (without forcing your visitors to download and install a font)

Comment: @Curtis F: Ah, thank you. What the fantasy refers to?

Comment: @HugoUchoBruno On Chrome, it looks like Impact. On IE/Edge it looks very similar to Monotype Corsiva, but it's not quite the same.

Comment: @Curtis F: You missunderstood me I meant this https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#fantasy but still thanks.